# Motherboard compatibility with graphic card

Tags: compatibility, motherboard

I have an `ABIT SG 95` motherboard and wanted to upgrade my graphics card to a `DDR3 Asus GeForce GT 210`. The motherboard has DDR2 memory, so I wanted to ask if the motherboard would accept this graphics card if I were to get it?

Answer (score 4):

The motherboard's memory does not matter. What matters is what type of PCI and PCI Express slots( or even AGP if an old board ) you have on your mother board. The selected mother board that you own has a PCI 2.0 express x16 slot and x1 slot. This is what matters. So, you match the PCI x16 slot with graphics cards of the same type. The selected graphics card that you want does support PCI Express x16 mother boards ( as do most because PCI Express x16 is the standard ). Although, personally, I would try and find a better graphics card because the memory interface for that one is only 64 bits. At least, for a minimum, I typically get above 128 bits, 192, 256, etc. That all depends on how much you like to play games and want better performance from games however. [This](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-550ti) is my card and it does all the gaming I need.

Comment: might be less of an issue, considering its an older board, and has got a (eww) s3 graphics adaptor - the gforce should be a pretty significant upgrade. You're right that graphics card ram (most higher end cards have some flavour of GDDR - video cards with DDR3 tend to be niche, such as passively cooled cards) dosen't have to match the type on the motherboard, however.

Answer (score 2):

The memory on the motherboard is different from the memory on the graphical card.  Each has its own controller(s).

This means you can use any graphical card, regardless of its memory.

<sup>Well, not quite any, but not due to RAM limitations. And AGP card will still not fit in an ISA bus :)</sup>

Comment: Just to make sure, will the DDR 3 graphics card work with my DDR 2 motherboard?

Comment: Yes, it will work.